# How can I set the program name for sybase connections in jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, connection, sybase

I can do it in C, and I can do it in perl, but I don't see how to set the program name on sybase connections using jdbc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found it here: http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1009812
"APPLICATIONNAME" is a property you can pass in the list of properties to the connect() function.